# how to add default value to uncheck checkboxes in html form and pass it to MySQL database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create columns for each and every checkboxes values in MySQL database. I want to pass 'YES' to checked checkboxes and 'NO' for the uncheck check boxes. when I use following code and submit it MySQL database using php, still uncheck checkboxes does not show 'NO' value in MySQL database.

```
<input type="hidden" value="NO" name="MBBS" >
<input type="checkbox" value="YES" name="MBBS" >
<label for="MBBS">MBBS</label><br>

<input type="hidden" value="NO" name="MD" >
<input type="checkbox" value="YES" name="MD" >
<label for="MD">M.D</label><br>
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you with the information you've provided.
Are your inputs wrapped inside a form tag?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Please share more details. How is the given problem related to PHP or MySQL? You haven't shared any such code

Comment: Yes. this is a piece of whole code. Simply, I want to know that how to pass 'NO' value for unchecked checkboxes in html form. It means I want to assign 'NO' value for PHP variable when user uncheck and submit the form.   I used following method in php form $mm = $_POST['MBBS'] to get value

Comment: And what _did_ you actually get with that? Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? (If not, please go and do that first of all now.)

Comment: Along with the hidden fields, what you've got should work. What actual _debugging_ have you done? Add `var_dump($_POST);` to your PHP code, and submit the form again. Tell us what it outputs. (That's assuming your form is submitted via POST of course, we can't see that). Also check your browser's Network tool and examine the form submission request, to see what the payload actually is.

Comment: Thanks for contributions and comments. I resolved that issue from following Php code. Lately I have to know that uncheck checkbox values can't be submitted to server from POST method. 
        if(isset($_POST['MBBS'])){
        $MBBS = $_POST['MBBS'];
        }
        else{
        $MBBS = 'NO';
        }

Comment: Your hidden fields should be making that unnecessary, though.